# Check particular value in a list

Tags: apex, list

I have a list. In the list, I have ids and names. May I know how to check if a name is in the list or not?

Its like if the name 'Ali' in the list, OwnerID = id [Id value takes from the list]

```
trigger UpdateRecordOwner on Centive__c (before insert, before update) {
    List<user> mylist = [select id, name from user where UserRole.name like'HO%'];
    set<string> myset = new set<string>(); 
    
    For(user m :mylist){ 
        myset.add(m.name); 
    } 
    
    for (Centive__c centive: Trigger.new) {
        if(myset.contains(centive.HOT__c)){
            //centive.OwnerId = mylist.id;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: We can’t really help you with any code. Can you add a code snippet to your question?

Comment: Done provide the code

Comment: You are using the wrong collections. You need a `Map<String, User>`, not a `List` and a `Set`.  But you'll have to think through what should happen if (a) there's more than one user with the same name and (b) there's no user with a given name.

Answer (score 0):

As David mentions, there are some edge cases for you to consider when matches are found but here is how you can iterate through your Users and assign an `OwnerId` to the `Centive` record using the `Map` collection type.

```
Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User where UserRole.name like'HO%']);
for (User u : userMap.values()) {
    for (Centive__c centive: Trigger.new) {
        if(u.Name.contains(centive.HOT__c)){
            centive.OwnerId = u.id;
        } 
    }
}
```

Note, you may wish to use `contains()`, `equals()` or `==`.

Comment: Thank you, but `centive.OwnerId = u.id;` will take the last id from the map

Comment: @NewbieSalesforce you have to take into consideration Davids comment on your post i.e "But you'll have to think through what should happen if (a) there's more than one user with the same name and (b) there's no user with a given name."